# Visit to USA before F1 with a valid ESTA

Tags: visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, f1-visas

I am French, and next month I will move to the USA to study there. I can enter the US with my F1 visa only 30 days before the date on I-20. However, I would like to go to the US before this date for a week, for holidays (but I also plan to view some apartments). I already have a valid ESTA.
Do you think it is possible?